# Testing Django API login using credentials and djoser

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm currently trying to test my API's endpoint using Django. So far I've used the APITestCase, but I'm having issues when it comes to login and using my token.

I have a Clark user with a password ('1'), I log him in, retrieve his token and add it to the header before sending my request. But I'm still getting a "Bad Credential Error".

```
    connection_data = {'email':self.clark_user.email, 'password': '1'}
    self.client.login(email=self.clark_user.email, password='1')     

    token = self.client.post(settings.SERVER_HOST+'/api/v1/auth/login', connection_data)
    self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.data['auth_token'])

    response = self.client.patch(self.url_people, serializer.data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.client.logout()
```

My stack is the following:

- Django rest framework (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/)
- Djoser (https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser)

And

- from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
- from core.test_utils import BaseTest For my tests.

Are the lib I use for my tests.

Comment: Just as a side note. To me it would make sense to use a new client instance for your patch request, since when you send your patch request client is already logged in as clark and the client instance may store some session information.

Answer (score 3):

Django REST framework has `APIClient` class which serves this purpose. I think rather than getting `Token` over http, it can pulled out from DB directly. The code looks like

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

# Include an appropriate `Authorization:` header on all requests.
token = Token.objects.get(user__username=self.clark_user.username)
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)

response = client.patch(self.url_people, serializer.data, format='json')
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
client.logout()
```

Documentation can be found at [Testing Page](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#example).